# Why web goes screwed in sqared screens?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have a web (http://www.apnae.org) which works fine in some screens but not in squared ones (see image):
[image]

How can I solve it?
Thanks!

Dani

Answer (score 2):

You have `width: 1355px;` being applied to your table element which holds the content. This styling is being applied inline, like so:

```
<table style="width: 1355px; height: 378px;">
```

I'm not sure where exactly this is coming from, but the best thing to do would be to open the article in the Joomla backend, then view the source code for the article.

Out of all honesty though, I would **refrain from using tables** to structure your content unless you have data that needs to be displayed in a table format.